# Making parametric plot with matlab

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to plot and make my x and y axis be depended on a parameter?
For example, I'd like that my x axis will be divided to 0 1/10L 2/10L 3/10L....L
and to plot the function on that exact axis, is it possible?
This is what I tried:

```
x = 0:0.1*L:10*L
plot(x,func1(x))
hold on
plot(x+xShift,func2(x)+yShift)
grid on
```

the shifts I'm adding are just some shifts because  I'd like the second function to start from a different x and y.

Comment: `xtick`,`xticklabel` etc

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
L = 4;
xShift = 5;
yShift = 2;
y = @(x) x .^ 2;

x = 0:(0.1*L):(10*L);
x_shifted = x + xShift;

y = y(x);
y_shifted = y + yShift;

plot(x,y)
hold on;
plot(x_shifted,y_shifted)
hold off;

grid on;

ticks = 0:(10*L) + xShift;
set(gca,'XTick',ticks);

lim = max(y_shifted);
set(gca,'YLim',[0 max(y_shifted)]);
```

Output:

[image: Output]